# Find the identity of outliers in clustering

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, svd

I'm a newbie to machine learning and these days experimenting with Singular Value Decomposition(SVD). Based on the x and y values I have drawn following digram using `matplotlib`. I'm in the process of detecting abnormal activities of web users. 
In this diagram there are few points like outliers. I want to identify who belongs to these outliers.

To make it more understandable let's take following dataset.

original matrix based on web page access.

```
matrix = mat( [[1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0], [1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1],[1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0],[0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0],[1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0],[1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0],[1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0],[1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0]] )
```

x,y coordination after calculation of SVD.

```
x = [-0.34095692,-0.34044722,-0.27155318,-0.21320583,-0.44657865,-0.19587836, -0.29414279, -0.3948753 ,-0.21655774 , -0.34857087]
y = [0.16305762,0.38554548, 0.10412536, -0.57981103, 0.17927523, -0.22612216, -0.34569697, 0.30463137,0.01301744,-0.42661108]
```

What I want is to find who belongs to a given data point. Like wise in a large data set plot how to find the identity of outliers? Hope you understand my question.

[image]

Comment: It will be clearer if you can explain a little bit on what is web page access, and what is the points you are drawing. It seems like x and y are the first two columns of orthogonal matrix from SVD, but I'm not quite sure how is it related to the figure

Comment: "outliers" is unfortunately a very vague term in general. One mans signal is another mans noise, someone said.

Comment: @lennon310 : Thanks for your comment. I'm going to identify abnormal users based on web page access. "Latent Semantic Analysis" in an approach in NLP which is used to identify similar words etc. I'm trying to use the same approach here?

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend looking through this:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html

the OneClassSVM can detect outliers: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.OneClassSVM.html
exampel with another dataset: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_oneclass.html